# deleteAll() vs deleteAllInBatch() produce different results on Hibernate Entities with '@Where' clause

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Using JpaRepository `deleteAll()` produce `org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException` on Entities with many to one relation (where the "one" has a where clause)

I am using a `@Where` clause on an entity to perform soft deletion :

```java
@Where(clause = "enabled = true")
@Table(name = "customer")
public class CustomerEntity {
...
}
```

There is a `@ManyToOne` relation to `CustomerEntity` on another entity :

```java
@Entity
public abstract class CustomerEvent extends Event {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    private CustomerEntity customer;
...
}
```

With the following repository (`BirthdayEvent` extends `CustomerEvent`):

```java
@Repository
public interface BirthdayEventRepository extends JpaRepository<BirthdayEvent, Integer> {
  ...
}
```

Now lets say customer with id '1' has `enabled = false` and there is a birthday event associated to that customer.

Performing `birthdayEventRepository.deleteAll()` will produce the following error :

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: Unable to find org.example.app.entity.roles.customer.CustomerEntity with id 1; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find org.example.app.entity.roles.customer.CustomerEntity with id 1
```

On the other hand, using `deleteAllInBatch()` works just fine.

Trying to examine the Hibernate SQL trace I found out that on the `deleteAll()` method, hibernate is performing the following binding for all customers (even if not enabled) :

```
2019-12-12 10:57:20.204 TRACE 2545551 --- [pool-4-thread-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [1]
```

Using `deleteAllInBatch()` hibernate performs the same binding but only for 'enabled' customers.

Is that a bug or an expected behavior ? If this is expected can someone explains why it works this way ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We had a similar situation with "deleted" instances of entities annotated with `@Where(clause = "deleted = false")`. If those were referenced by another entity, working with the latter led to the same mentioned `javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException`.

Maybe I'm wrong, but you should see the same error when loading the event via `BirthdayEventRepository` and then accessing its `CustomerEntity`.

I can only guess from the docs that `CrudRepository.deleteAll` loads all events before deleting them whereas `JpaRepository.deleteAllInBatch` doesn't.

[CrudRepository.deleteAll](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#deleteAll--)

> `void deleteAll()`
>
> Deletes all entities *managed* by the repository.

[JpaRepository.deleteAllInBatch](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#deleteAllInBatch--)

> `void deleteAllInBatch()`
>
> Deletes all entities in a batch call.

---

**Update 2019-12-13**

I was curious, setup a test and recorded database accesses with a profiler.

1) `deleteAll()` starts by loading/selecting all records from database:

```
exec sp_executesql N'select user0_.id as id1_11_, ... from [user] user0_'
```

This was followed by some other reads to load/check for referenced objects. Then it started to delete one object by the other:

```
exec sp_executesql N'delete from [user] where id=@P0        ',N'@P0 bigint',1

exec sp_executesql N'delete from [user] where id=@P0        ',N'@P0 bigint',2
```

2) In contrast, `deleteAllInBatch()` tries to delete all instances directly:

```
exec sp_executesql N'delete from [user]'
```

Conclusion is that (2) goes faster since it performs no checks while (1) is more accurate, to put it simply.